# Submit form to specific url

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, forms

Ok so I have this form:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "navbar-form navbar-left form-inline", @role = "search" }))
            {
                var numberOfVideos = SessionHelper.NumberOfVideos;
                <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search (@numberOfVideos videos)" class="form-control" name="searchString" id="searchString">
                    <label for="searchString" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" rel="tooltip" title="search"></label>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
```

upon submit, it goes to /Home/Search?searchString={searchStringValue}

I would like it to go to /search/{searchStringValue} (I have a nice routing attribute there)

Comment: Easiest way is to override the form submission and just use javascript.

Comment: Do you use default routing? Show your routing code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you choose to use JavaScript over the slightly more correct and maintainable back end fix,

```
form.onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = '/search/' + encodeURIComponent(form.elements[controlName].value);
}
```

The main benefit to using JavaScript for this is how short the code is.